# while importing csv file into table in PgAdmin i am facing failed Process issue ?how to solve this?

Tags: database, postgresql, pgadmin

[this is what i am facing while importing a csv file in to a table in pgAdmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFhYq.png)

i am tring again and again but its not working

--command " "\copy public.attacks_2023 ("Date ", "City ", "Latitude ", "Longitude", "Location", "Location_Category", "Influencing_Event ", "Target_type", "Killed", "Injured", "Attack_Type") FROM 'C:/Users/WALEED~1/Desktop/ATTACK~1.CSV' OIDS DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER ENCODING 'UTF8' QUOTE '"' ESCAPE '''';""

ERROR: syntax error at or near "OIDS"
LINE 1: ...Killed" , "Injured" , "Attack_Type" ) FROM STDIN OIDS DELI...

Comment: `--command` means you aren't running the command in pgAdmin, you're running it in the command line, perhaps using `psql`. You need to escape the double quotes inside the command string. How you do that depends on the shell you use (PowerShell? CMD ?) A better idea would be to create the command string in a shell variable and pass it to psql to reduce the amount of quoting

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.